# How can I test belongs_to, has_one, or has_many associations with test::unit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, testunit

I'm pretty new to rails testing and I tried using shoulda but it breaks whatever model I put it in so I figured I should just test them manually.

So my question to you oh great experts of SO is this:

How can I use test::unit to test that a model is associated with another model?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, the most obvious solution would be something like this:

```
user = User.create(name: 'User')
2.times { user.friends.create(name: 'Other User') }

assert_equal(2, user.friends.count, "Unexpected associated records count")
```

but this is basically more like testing rails itself, you should not bother with that.

I would just check if `user.respond_to?(:friends)`. But, of course, it will fail if someone defines a method with that name

Comment: This seems to work well enough. If someone makes a method name friend I guess we'll just change it. Thanks!

Comment: Would the first way be the only way to test a "has_many" association?

Comment: I figured it out. I can check if it responds to :new